# how openGL handles data service like socket service or http service?

Tags: opengl

it is said that openGl is a standAlone between the operation system,So i think openGl offer the redering ability,but how about the data service , can it handle http service or socket through it's own api? if not, it should invoke the api from the operation system ,if in this case, the codes contains remote data must be writing for different os,am i right?

Comment: flagging for not constructive

Comment: 'standAlone between the operation system' Makes no sense to me in the context of OpenGL. 'but how about the data service' Shows that you did no research at all, so does 'can it handle http service or socket'. You clearly know nothing of OpenGL, because it has **nothing** to do with those things. OpenGL only does rendering, it is an API to let you use your graphics card. It forms a layer between your code and your GPU driver. If you did **any** research you would know all these things.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is a *graphics* system. It doesn't handle "data services", "socket services", "http services", or anything of the kind. It just draws stuff.

Where you get the stuff for it to draw is *entirely* up to you.